# SharePoint workflow lookup multiple value

Tags: workflow

Assuming I have 2 list, SourceList and WorkingList.

**SourceList**

- Team
- Manager

**WorkingList**

- TeamColumn (lookup the field Team in SourceList and allow multiple values)
- ResponsibleManagers

So, my question is, if users enter multiple teams in TeamColumn in WorkingList, is it possible to use workflow to determine a list of ResponsibleManagers based on the SourceList?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2010 or later, you could use "additional fields" in TeamColumn lookup field settings.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using SharePoint 2007... any ways this can be done in SP2007 as well?